# Disable collapsing in Silverlight DataGrid group header

Tags: silverlight, datagrid, grouping

How can I disable the collapsing in Silverlight DataGrid group header row? I don't want to hide that row!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to the Xaml of your data grid:-

```
        <sdk:DataGrid.RowGroupHeaderStyles>
            <Style TargetType="sdk:DataGridRowGroupHeader">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
            </Style>
        </sdk:DataGrid.RowGroupHeaderStyles>
```

Comment: It also disables all controls in it.  It would be nice to disable the expand/collapse but still keep the interaction possible with controls inside.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
private void datagrid_LoadingRowGroup(object sender, DataGridRowGroupHeaderEventArgs e)
{
   e.RowGroupHeader.IsHitTestVisible = false;
}
```